# Can I access gl_PointCoord in a vertex shader?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl

`gl_PointCoord` returns the 2D vector representing the UV mapping coordinates at that pixel. But it appears to be only available in the fragment shader.  I know that you can send values from the vertex shader to the fragment shader with `varying`, but can you send it the other way? Can I get the UV coordinates for the current vertex?

Is it possible access `gl_PointCoord` in a vertex shader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"UV mapping coordinates at that pixel"* - Indeed, but in the vertex shader you don't have any pixels. You're missing how point sprites actually work. A single vertex shader invocation putting out a `gl_PointSize` larger than 1 pixel results in multiple fragment shader invocations for this point (because the point, well, covers multiple pixels). And those fragments get their `gl_PointCoord` based on their position inside this larger point sprite. But each point sprite covering multiple fragments always results from a single vertex. So conceptually this single per-vertex `gl_PointCoord` would just be `(0.5, 0.5)` for each vertex, but in the end even this doesn't make sense because there really is no notion of any pixels let alone per-pixel UV-coordinates inside a vertex shader.

*"but can you send it the other way"* - And I'm sure this was meant rather informally, since of course you cannot send any data from a fragment shader to the vertex shader, as the graphics pipeline only works in a single direction.

**EDIT:** Regarding your comment, if not using point sprites, the `gl_PointCoord` variable doesn't have any meaning at all. You cannot use it as a general UV-coordinate (how should the fragment shader come up with a reasonable value). For that you have to put out a valid texture coordinate youself from your vertex shader (as a `varying`) that then gets interpolated over the fragments to be accessed in the fragment shader, maybe ultimately passed into the vertex shader as an additional `attribute`, as is usual.

Comment: I'm not making point sprites. I have some long skinny strips that I would like to move the verticies of, based on the UV coordinate because it's a nice handy normalized float that tells me how far along the strip I am. Or does `gl_PointCoord` only work with point sprites, and not general meshes?

Comment: I realize now the error of my thought process here. I obviously can't "send" anything from frag to vert shader now that I think about it more. After a more diving into example though I think `uv` is simply the identifier I want, which works from a vertex shader. Thanks for the clarifying explanation.